# Multibit notification

Tags: multibit

I have  a blockchain.info account and I would like to move my wallet from the web interface to the multibit client. 
However, I need that once an incoming transaction have been confirmed I need to call  web service to update a remote database.
Is this possible to do this without modify the multibit code?
I have some experience in Java but this seems beyhon my current skill.
In case I can evaluate other client.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

As MultiBit HD is targeted for end users it does not have any external API.

Have a look at the WalletTool in the bitcoinj examples module (the Bitcoin network code MultiBit uses).

It gives you a command line interface into bitcoin confirmations.
It's much simpler than the MultiBit HD code so will be much easier to tweak to do what you want.